# mysql workbench takes too long time to apply a simple query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-2013

this is my query,

```
    SELECT 
    COUNT(a.ref) AS refoct2015,
    COUNT(b.ref) AS refspet2015,
    COUNT(c.ref) AS refoct2014,
    port_ID
FROM
    report AS a
        JOIN
    report_sept2015 AS b USING (port_ID)
        JOIN
    report_oct2014 AS c USING (port_ID)
GROUP BY port_ID , a.booking_date , b.booking_date , c.booking_date
```

but sql takes more than 15 min to give me a result when it doesn't stop working.
I restart it many times, changed the reading time (Edit>Preference>etc..) but nothing still very slow

Comment: Can you post the "Explain Select..." info?

Comment: probably a lot of rows and/or no indexes

Comment: how many rows in each table?

Comment: Id like to select the number(count) of reference number by port Id (refoct2015 -> refreence october 2015), thanks for editing @Jaydee

Comment: how about a query where you have some columns not in the group by, some columns in the group by, and all that are in the group by are in aggregate functions like count. That is something you are not showing

Comment: @PaulF about 20k - 30K each (3 tables)

Comment: so something like select a,b,c,count(x),count(y) from t1 group by a,b,c

Comment: Are you sure you should be joining the tables - seems more like you need to use a union of some sort

Comment: @PaulF i ran other quiries by the same join before, and it worked well

Comment: Put "Explain " in front of the statement and then run it. Post the result as part of your question.

Comment: Are you sure you want the counts(*) before the joins occur (Presently your counts are artificially inflated by the joins) or is there significance to the joined count?

Comment: '**1 SIMPLE b ALL     739 Using temporary; Using filesort
1 SIMPLE c ALL     8943 Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
1 SIMPLE a ALL     11449 Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)**'  this is the result @Jaydee

Comment: @xQbert yes I would like to have the count before the join occures

Comment: Port_ID needs to be indexed in each table. Also, see xQbert's answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the count before the joins occur then you have to generate the count before you join.

This is one method to accomplish that:

```
SELECT A.Port_ID, A.refoct2015, B.refSept2015 , C.RefOct2014 
FROM (SELECT Port_ID, Booking_Date, count(Ref) as refoct2015 
      FROM report
      GROUP BY Port_Id, Booking_Date) A
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT Port_ID, Booking_Date, count(Ref) as refSept2015 
      FROM Report_sept2015
      GROUP BY Port_Id, Booking_Date) B 
  ON A.Port_ID = B.Port_ID
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT Port_ID, Booking_Date, count(Ref) as RefOct2014 
      FROM report_oct2014
      GROUP BY Port_Id, Booking_Date) C 
  ON B.Port_ID = C.Port_ID
```

Though it seems odd to include booking_date and not join on it...

If I have in table A 100 distinct dates and in table B 100 distinct dates, and in table c 100 distinct dates, then your result set would be 100*100*100 assuming each share the same port_Id... probably why its taking 15 minutes...  Sure you're not missing a join?

This seems to make more sense to me...

```
SELECT A.Port_ID, A.refoct2015, B.refSept2015 , C.RefOct2014 
FROM (SELECT Port_ID, Booking_Date, count(Ref) as refoct2015 
      FROM report
      GROUP BY Port_Id, Booking_Date) A
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT Port_ID, Booking_Date, count(Ref) as refSept2015 
      FROM Report_sept2015
      GROUP BY Port_Id, Booking_Date) B 
  ON A.Port_ID = B.Port_ID
 and A.Booking_date= B.Booking_date
INNER JOIN 
     (SELECT Port_ID, Booking_Date, count(Ref) as RefOct2014 
      FROM report_oct2014
      GROUP BY Port_Id, Booking_Date) C 
  ON B.Port_ID = C.Port_ID
 and A.Booking_date= B.Booking_date
```

However this implies that if dates and port IDs are not in all tables then you'd have a problem. with data elimination due to the inner join.  Normally I'd use a Full outer join to resolve this but mySQL doesn't support it.  You'd have to use Outer joins and unions to simulate the behavior.

So rather than continue to guess at what you're after.  Explain what those tables are for and what you're trying to do accomplish in plain English; in your original question by editing it.

I'm afraid we're falling into the [XY problem here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Why is booking_date relevant if it's not in the select?

It really seems like you're trying to pivot the data from these three tables by date...but then not showing date....

Are you after something like

```
Port_Id   Date    Oct2015  Sept2015  Oct2014
1        1/1/2015     500       250        0
1        1/2/2015     100        60        0
2        1/1/2015     100       540       60
```

?

Comment: hey, you are exactly right I want pivot the table by date but I don't need to see them reason why I do not include booking_date in the select clause. I finally found the solution. by removing the booking (as I am using three different period) and select what I need then inner join. thank for your help !